# Cordova camera plugin error with destinationType option

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have a problem with the camera plugin of cordova.

When I write `destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` or "FILE_URI" in options of `getPicture()`, I have this error:

> [phonegap] [console.error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'DATA_URL'
>   of undefined [phonegap]     at d.e.takePicture
>   (file:///data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/files/phonegapdevapp/www/js/app.min.js:13:13609)
>   [phonegap]     at fn (eval at 
>   (file:///data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/files/phonegapdevapp/www/js/app.min.js:11:32101),
>   :2:224) [phonegap]     at i
>   (file:///data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/files/phonegapdevapp/www/js/app.min.js:12:18522)
>   [phonegap]     at d.$eval
>   (file:///data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/files/phonegapdevapp/www/js/app.min.js:10:20470)
>   [phonegap]     at d.$apply
>   (file:///data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/files/phonegapdevapp/www/js/app.min.js:10:20696)
>   [phonegap]     at HTMLButtonElement.
>   (file:///data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/files/phonegapdevapp/www/js/app.min.js:12:18574)
>   [phonegap]     at HTMLButtonElement.Gt.n
>   (file:///data/data/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/files/phonegapdevapp/www/js/app.min.js:8:30670)

If I dont write this option, camera launch correctly, but I can't have the url of the img.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using phonegap build? Anyway try your luck with this :) ... destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL

Comment: destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL WORKS! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use`destinationType:navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL`